# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{k^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Can someone please help me simplifying this sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{k^2}$$

Wolframalpha fails (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_k=0%5En%20%28binom%28n,k%29%20%2a%202%5E%28k%5E2%29%29)).

Thanks in advance.

The sum counts the number of (labelled) digraphs (with loops) with vertex set $V \subseteq [n]$.

Comment: I must say that the $2^{k^2}$ factor makes me pessimistic that this will resolve to something simple... [OEIS knows nothing either.](http://oeis.org/A135748)

Comment: With $2^k$ everything is fine: the sum resolves to $3^n$.

Comment: I think you entered it wrong, Wolframalpha seems to read it  as the bracket $\{ k=0\}$ is missing. Then it becomes :$ \sum_k=0^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{k^2}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with J.M.'s comment above that this is not going to resolve into something simple.  Asymptotically, though, the last term will dominate, and maybe that will be useful.  We have 
$$2^{n^2} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{k^2} \leq 2^{n^2}\left(1 + \frac{2n^2}{4^n}\right).$$
The relative remainder term $R(n) = \frac{2n^2}{4^n}$ goes to $0$ fairly quickly as $n \to \infty$, and so $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{k^2} \approx 2^{n^2}$.

*Derivation*: The terms in the sum are strictly increasing.  Since $n \geq k$, for $k \geq 1$ we have $$\frac{\binom{n}{k} 2^{k^2}}{\binom{n}{k-1}2^{(k-1)^2}} = 2^{2k-1}\left(\frac{n}{k}-1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \geq 2^{2k-1}\left(1-1+\frac{1}{k}\right) = \frac{2^{2k}}{2k}> 1.$$

Therefore,
$$2^{n^2} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{k^2} = 2^{n^2} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} 2^{k^2} \leq 2^{n^2} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{n-1} 2^{(n-1)^2} = 2^{n^2} + n^2 2^{n^2-2n+1}$$
$$= 2^{n^2}\left(1 + \frac{2n^2}{4^n}\right).$$

Comment: I like the inclusion of the derivation. (+1) Your error term is better than mine: $$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^{k^2}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^{(n-k)^2}\\
&=2^{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^{-k(2n-k)}\\
&\le2^{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^{-kn}\\
&=2^{n^2}\left(1+2^{-n}\right)^n
\end{align}
$$ and $\left(1+2^{-n}\right)^n\to1$ pretty fast, but not as fast as $1+\frac{2n^2}{4^n}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (BTW: Is there a connection between the fact that the error term decreases very quickly and the fact that there is no simple resolution? Is there a counter example?)

Comment: @Hans: You're welcome!  With respect to your question, I don't know.  And while I don't think there is a nice closed-form answer, I can't prove that there isn't one, either.